# Gerrit plugin-manager doesn't show plugins

Tags: gerrit

I have a `Gerrit v2.15` on a linux machine and I'm the administrator in Gerrit.

I installed the Gerrit plugin-manager under gerrit/plugins with command :

`wget https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.15/job/plugin-plugin-manager-bazel-master-stable-2.15/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bazel-genfiles/plugins/plugin-manager/plugin-manager.jar`

But nothing uploads in Gerrit UI in tab Plugins. I only see the Installed, as before.

In gerrit/logs/**error.log** I can read out the following:

```
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,366] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loaded plugin plugin-manager, version v2.15-1-g27c3d2935d
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,367] [plugin-manager-preloader] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.manager.OnStartStop : Start-up: pre-loading list of plugins from registry
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,902] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.git.GarbageCollectionRunner : Ignoring missing gc schedule configuration
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,902] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.config.ScheduleConfig : accountDeactivation schedule parameter "accountDeactivation.interval" is not configured
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,902] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.change.ChangeCleanupRunner : Ignoring missing changeCleanup schedule configuration
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,946] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon : Started Gerrit SSHD-CORE-1.6.0 on *:29418
[2018-06-15 08:54:26,949] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server : jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
[2018-06-15 08:54:28,040] [main] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.gitiles.HttpModule : No /opt/gerrit/etc/gitiles.config; assuming defaults
[2018-06-15 08:54:28,847] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler : Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@62672ad5{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[2018-06-15 08:54:28,869] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector : Started ServerConnector@38503309{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{127.0.0.1:8081}
[2018-06-15 08:54:28,890] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server : Started @20170ms
[2018-06-15 08:54:28,893] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Gerrit Code Review 2.15.1 ready
[2018-06-15 08:54:44,819] [plugin-manager-preloader] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.manager.OnStartStop : 45 plugins successfully pre-loaded
```

What have i missed?

Is it some permission settings that is wrong or configuration in gerrit.config that has to be done?

Directory gerrit/plugin has permissions set to: drwxr-xr-x

*Note* : I've tried restarting Gerrit.

*Good to know*: We are using nginx. That might be useful info. 
I know very little about how nginx works.

[What it looks like in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaLoS.png)

Comment: Are you able to access the page {gerrit-url}/plugins/plugin-manager/static/index.html? Replace {gerrit-url} according to your gerrit URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin-manager only works in the Old UI. If you're using the new PolyGerrit UI first click on "Switch to Old UI" link at the right/down on the page. Then the plugin-manager can be access at: Plugins > Manage menu.

If you're not able to see the "Manage" option in the Old UI check the following:

. Verify if you're logged in Gerrit with an Admin user (you need to have "Administrate Server" permission in All-Projects project). There're an specific permission to access Plugins > Installed item (called "View Plugins") but this permission doesn't work the same way to Plugins > Manage one.

. Verify if you have the following set in the GERRIT_SITE/etc/gerrit.config file:

```
[plugins]
    allowRemoteAdmin = true
```

Maybe this can resolve your issue.

Comment: I' was in the old UI, but I only see the installed ones. If I click on the plugin-manager link I'll get to the documentation page and it only shows me name and version of the plugin. I added an image just to clarify.

Comment: When you click on "Plugins" you should have two options: "Installed" and "Manage". Did you not see the "Manage" option?

Comment: No, just installed. I added a picture under a link in my post. “What it looks like in the UI”.

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: SOLVED! It was the gerrit.config-file. I didn't have that line in the file. I can't recall that I had seen the documentation about that, but probably just missed it. Thanks a lot!